# Creating a reference line among LiDAR points and retrieving distances between them?

Tags: arcpy, lidar, linear-referencing, las

I have a LAS dataset which contains points with x and y coordinates. For further analysis I need a new dimension which can be adjusted as the dataset requires. To make it understandable I made this (beautiful paint drawing):

[image]

So in this case I need a V values which shows the distance along the V (North-East; South-West)

How is it possible to create these values?

I'd like to do it in Python, but any other working method is welcomed.

(I have ArcGIS 10.2.2 [built in 2.7 python], python 3.5)

Comment: It is hard to tell from your description and drawing but you may be describing Linear Referencing and adding route measures.

Comment: Partly yes. I changed the picture a bit to show what the result I expect

Comment: That makes it look even more like linear referencing, but how to apply to a LAS dataset could be challenging.

Comment: Well I can gather the X and Y coordinates from the LAS dataset, I wonder if those enough to make the Linear Referencing

Comment: I'm thinking that you may be dealing with billions of points, but I don't work with LAS datasets, so my concerns on performance may be unfounded.

Comment: Yes, those are a lot of points, but I have a strong pc and right now I only need the method

Comment: I've never worked with lidar (.las) files either, so I know close to nothing about them. Would it be possible to turn the problem into a standard point and polyline problem (points as the x's and polyline as the dotted-line), then convert the results back into LAS format?